# How do you emit a set of values over time with RXjs?

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I'm looking to take a series of values emitted by an Observable like this, `Rx.Observable.of(["add", "edit", "destroy"])`, but I want each value to be emitted every 5 seconds.

Currently I'm faking this using `setTimer()` and a `Subject` like this.

```
const actions$ = new Rx.Subject();

setTimeout(() => { actions$.next("add");  }, 5 * 1000);
setTimeout(() => { actions$.next("edit"); }, 10 * 1000);
setTimeout(() => { actions$.next("destroy"); }, 15 * 1000);
```

But it seems like there's probably a way to do this without as much handwaving. How can I do this without using `setTimeout()`?

Comment: You forgot to `.subscribe()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are many ways you could do this with RxJS.

One would be to create an `interval` observable and use it together with `zip` to emit a name each time the `interval` observable emits.

The `zip` operator merges the emissions of the observables it's passed whenever each has emitted a value. And the optional selector is used here to ignore the incremental integers emitted by the `interval` observable.

```js
const names = Rx.Observable.from(["add", "edit", "destroy"]);
const interval = Rx.Observable.interval(500);
Rx.Observable
  .zip(names, interval, (name, i) => name)
  .subscribe(name => console.log(name));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs@5/bundles/Rx.min.js"></script>
```

And I've reduced the interval to `500` because I'm impatient.

Comment: Ha ha. I suppose 5 seconds is a little long to wait @cartant. Thanks for the quick reply. This is exactly the kind of solution I knew had to exist. :)